# Is this really an IPS panel?

Tags: linux, display, edid

I recently bought a used HP EliteBook Folio 1040, which was advertised as having an IPS panel.

However, comparing it to my Dell XPS 15, which definitely has an IPS panel, the display seems to have washy colors and not-so-good viewing angles.

Therefore, I'm trying to find out whether I was scammed by the seller.

This is the information I extracted from EDID:

```
Manufacturer: SDC Model 5441 Serial Number 0
Made in year 2012
...
ASCII string: XG69V
```

Can anyone confirm whether this is an IPS panel? I'd also be interested in ways to extract additional information about this panel (on linux).

Comment: HP unfortunately both offers TN and IPS displays with this laptop. My reason for buying this one was that it was supposed to have the IPS panel. I don't think it would be that obvious if someone replaced it, as I've done that multiple times myself.

Comment: You tagged this as "linux". Can you please explain what this has to do with Linux?

Answer (score 0):

"the display seems to have washy colors and not-so-good viewing angles."

probably a sign it is not IPS.

[Also see this page](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-software-that-can-show-my-laptops-monitor-is-TN-panel-or-IPS)

Both the G1 and G2 of that model are both regular backlit LED panels as far as my research shows.

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-folio-1040-g1-notebook-pc/5405384/document/c04132545#AbT2

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-folio-1040-g2-notebook-pc/7393377/document/c04556462#AbT2

Comment: The models you link feature devices with 1600x900 and 1920x1080 screens. The one I purchased has a 1366x768 screen. Also, the notebookcheck.com review mentions an IPS model.

Comment: I guess they offered an upgrade that never got in the specs, typical HP.